# dotnet publish does not pull NuGet packages

Tags: asp.net, linux, .net-core

I am trying to automate deployment of an ASP.NET WebAPI on a Linux server using the following command:

`dotnet publish --configuration Release`

However, when adding a new NuGet package to the solution, and then trying to run the `dotnet publish` command, I get an error because the compiler does not know the new package. Is there a way to tell the dotnet command to pull all NuGet packages ? (I'm kind of looking for an equivalent for pip install -r requirements.txt in python).

For information, I add the NuGet packages via VisualStudio without compiling the solution.

Edit : it seems like, unless I build the solution in VisualStudio, just adding a NuGet packet will only add the packet name and version in the file projectname.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json, but will not add the PackageReference projectname.csproj file, hince the not pulling new packets issue.

Comment: Are you running with --no-restore?
dotnet publish should implicitly restore all packages. If you have a custom package source, you will need to provide that

Comment: No, I put in the whole command line I'm using, I don't set the parameter --no-restore

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using some CI/CD pipeline which could publish your web application somewhere.
Feels like you are missing steps before publish:

```
      # Restore (restores nuget packages)
        run: dotnet restore
      # Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      # Test (if you have tests in project)
        run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal 
      # Publish 
        run: dotnet publish --no-restore --no-build --framework netcoreapp3.1
```

May be this link may be helpful: [github .net CI/CD](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-net)